# Pure css popup submenu not displaying properly

Tags: html, css, layout

I've created menu drop down menu in pure css,

here, parent div have `position:relative` and the menu popup have `position:absolute`,

when the menu hovered the submenu will appear as `display:block`,

but here, hovering `sarees` (first menu) the popup menu appears perfectly, but hovering the last menu `webmenus`, the popup appers at wrong position (different position). The images uploaded below

I want to make the same position with all **submenu popups** like `sarees`'s submenu popup have.
is there any css hack for this .. ?

Images :

**I want this position for all menus**

[image: I want this position for all menus]

**The menu Displaying at wrong position**

[image: The menu Displaying at wrong position]

Comment: Let me know if it's what you were after. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you are using `position: relative` to the menus, including the drop down menus. That is the why you are having this issue. You set the menu as *absolute* and it is understood as relatively to its respective parent. If you remove the `position: relative` it will set absolute position relatively to the page.

**Update:**

See a Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mLbaxgf0)

and compare to this another Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mLbaxgf0/1/)

 Did you see the difference?

***Sorry if my english is bad***

Comment: i forget it .. fixed with removing `position: relative` .. thanks for figuring out.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:relative;` to each `.menuTemplate1 li`

That way the menu will open always on the left side, as your image shows.